# Instagram permissions approval issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-permissions

We submitted Instagram permissions for review: instagram_basic and instagram_manage_comments.

Response was: "Your screencast does not show a test user logging into Instagram in your app. Please update your screencast to show the complete login experience.".

On Facebook login, we get user's pages he manages and then when selecting a page we get Instagram account connected to the page (if connected). Here we get Instagram username and Business ID. Another question is for permission instagram_manage_comments. Receiving users comments on post is handled via webhooks. In our DB we save that comment and then admin user can reply to that comment directly from admin panel.

Can anyone tell me how to login with Instagram test account? I tried with Facebook Test users, logged in, then created a page, and created the Instagram account. But how to try all functions with test user when I can not log in Instagram account and create a post and comment on post?

Thanks

Comment: Can’t you go through that with a _real_ user account, one that has a role in your app?

Comment: Yes I can and it works well.

Comment: did you figure this out? I am facing the same issues

Comment: @RobA we got approved, just in Facebook test Page log in with real Instagram account and show them that in video. Also, show Facebook Login popup where are all permissions listed (user accepts)

Comment: @consigliere Hello! Can you please contact me back about your approval process? Thanks! my Fb name is v.sobolev and same email name on gmail. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @consigliere,i added the test user but i can't figure how to go forward , what steps should i follow after that ?

Comment: @ghaliano you should log in with real instagram account